# Python gtk3 renderer text with autocompletion

Tags: python, gtk3, cellrenderer

I have a tree-view with some columns. One of them is my "mp3" column. And I have a list of mp3 names. I want to make the cell-renderer-text editable and add completion while typing. I saw some examples but they used Gtk.EntryCompletion() and Gtk.Entry(). I only use CellRendererText() , therefore I don't how to do it.

```
                renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
                column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("New MP3", renderer_text, text=i)
                renderer_text.set_property("editable",True)
                renderer_text.connect("edited",self.text_newmp3_edited)
                self.treeview.append_column(column)
```